# Run Heroku Container

Tags: docker, heroku, flask, containers

I have pushed the docker image with flask and other libraries. It was working fine in local container.

In the flask it is app.run(), earlier we were specifying port 5000 as well.

I deployed the stack to heroku and it is successful. but when I try to test it in the browser by typing `predictpy.heroku.com:5000` is erroring out:
Port `5000` I am trying

`predictpy.heroku.com` refused to connect.

Any idea? Am I missing something when deploying the flask application to Heroku?

Comment: also I open the terminal and run the terminal in heroku and manually triggered the flask py code. it is running on http://127.0.0.1:5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have specified a `web` process in your procfile. It is "the only process type that can receive external HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers" and it listens to port 80. So if you haven't do so, add proxy traffic from 5000 to 80 by  `web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app` and visit `predictpy.heroku.com`

Comment: Do I need to install gunicorn separately? 

Now I am getting Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ , but as you mentioned I did created Procfile and wrote the command 
`run:
  web: gunicorn app:app`

will it expose the flask application to port 80? can you please brief me?

Comment: check if you have gunicorn in your requirements.txt. `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app` will bind the port to a port that heroku injected via the env, then heroku's route takes charge routing it to port 80 on the virtual domain